# Как webview загрузиться из Cache

Tags: webview

Помогите разобраться. Пишу приложение с webview включил загрузку сache, все вроде работает но столкнулся с проблемой. Когда нет подключения к интернету, его перекрывает страница ошибки html из папки assets  в методе onReceivedError. Помогите пожалуйста, создать проверку, если интернет пропал и сache есть загрузиться принудительно с него, а если сache нет показать страницу ошибки html. Буду очень благодарен